# Custom Vertical tabcontrol alingnment issue in wpf

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, tabcontrol

i have created user control which has custom label and button. While add vertical tab it works perfectly.While add vertically with -90 rotation . it display correctly  but my label always start from center of the tab.

please help me to find my issue

Comment: Please explain more with some xaml.